# cannot access jupyter notebook on ec2 instance after installing virtualenv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

My jupyter notebook running from an ec2 instance has been working with no issues until I installed virtualenv using this command:
`sudo apt install virtualenv`

Since then, I cannot access jupyter on my browser. I have tried uninstalling virtualenv and restarting the instance, to no avail. I also tried to see if jupyter is running with this command:
`sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN`

Which returned this:

> jupyter-n 1433 ubuntu    7u  IPv4  24133      0t0  TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)

I also tried doing a wget on local, which got me this error:

> Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8888... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
> Retrying.

So I assume that the server is running, I just broke something inside, possibly a dependency or some sort of configuration. Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: How are you trying to access Jupyter (eg `localhost:8888` or `ip-address:8888`)? Exactly what happens when you try to connect? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the instance?

Comment: I'm accessing Jupyter remotely (ip-address:8888). When accessing from remote browser, it tried to load for a long time but then it says connection refused.

I also tried doing wget localhost:8888. I updated the question to include this result.

Comment: If `wget localhost:8888` is not working from the instance itself, then it suggests that the jupyter server is not running.